# Confusion about function handles in One vs. All Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, function-handle

I'm taking Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on coursera, and I'm pretty confused as to why one particular example works in the One vs. All classification:

```
function [all_theta] = oneVsAll(X, y, num_labels, lambda)
%ONEVSALL trains multiple logistic regression classifiers and returns all
%the classifiers in a matrix all_theta, where the i-th row of all_theta 
%corresponds to the classifier for label i
%   [all_theta] = ONEVSALL(X, y, num_labels, lambda) trains num_labels
%   logisitc regression classifiers and returns each of these classifiers
%   in a matrix all_theta, where the i-th row of all_theta corresponds 
%   to the classifier for label i

% Some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);
n = size(X, 2);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
all_theta = zeros(num_labels, n + 1);

% Add ones to the X data matrix
X = [ones(m, 1) X];

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: You should complete the following code to train num_labels
%               logistic regression classifiers with regularization
%               parameter lambda. 
%
% Hint: theta(:) will return a column vector.
%
% Hint: You can use y == c to obtain a vector of 1's and 0's that tell use 
%       whether the ground truth is true/false for this class.
%
% Note: For this assignment, we recommend using fmincg to optimize the cost
%       function. It is okay to use a for-loop (for c = 1:num_labels) to
%       loop over the different classes.
%
%       fmincg works similarly to fminunc, but is more efficient when we
%       are dealing with large number of parameters.
%
% Example Code for fmincg:
%
%     % Set Initial theta
%     initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
%     
%     % Set options for fminunc
%     options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);
% 
%     % Run fmincg to obtain the optimal theta
%     % This function will return theta and the cost 
%     [theta] = ...
%         fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)), ...
%                 initial_theta, options);
%

initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);

options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);

for i = 1:num_labels

    c = i * ones(size(y));
    fprintf('valores')
    [theta] = fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)), initial_theta, options);
    all_theta(i,:) = theta;

end


% =========================================================================


end
```

I'm particularlly confused about the line: `[theta] = fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)), initial_theta, options);`. `lrCostFunction` is defined to have parameters `theta, X, y, lambda`, so I don't know what the `t` is doing there.

Also, what is the purpose of wrapping `theta` in brackets: `[theta]`?

Any help on stepping through this code would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Andrew Ng covers this in good depth in his assignments as well as his Octave / MATLAB tutorials.  Also check the duplicate.  In addition, `theta` surrounded with `[]` is superfluous.  In general, you have a function that can return multiple outputs, so you usually have each variable you want captured by surrounding `[]` in a comma-separated list.  In this case, the function is only returning one variable, so syntactic sugar in MATLAB allows us to remove the `[]` in the case of one variable.  Otherwise, both surrounding the output variable with `[]` and omitting them makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a line where an anonymous function is defined. An anonymous function is like a short-hand definition of a function, and starts with an `@`, followed by parameters of this function (in your case `t`). This parameter `t` is passed on to the function `lrCostFunction()` as the first parameter, and is in fact the `theta` parameter. I.e., you are asking the function `fmincg()` to minimize the output of this anonymous function, which is a wrapper around `lrCostFunction()` so that you minimize over theta, while using `X`, `y` and `lambda` as defined outside the anonymous function definition.

To get a better understanding of anonymous functions, you can split the code:

```
 func_handle = @(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)) % anonymous function
 func_handle(initial_theta); % returns the cost at the initial_theta
 [theta] = fmincg(func_handle, initial_theta, options);
```

See the official [Matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for details on anonymous functions.

The brackets around `theta` are redundant.